# Decorator Pattern Unity Register Type Issue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator

i need to implement decorator pattern to expand class behaviour. I have an interface:

```
public interface  IExternalVerifierCaller
{
    VerificationProtocol Verify(VerificationItem verificationItem);
    VerificationProtocolBase Verify(VerificationItems verificationItems);
}
```

and realization of it which has a constructor:

```
public class FormatCheck4PxVerifierCaller : IExternalVerifierCaller
    {
        public FormatCheck4PxVerifierCaller(bool isPfrUfaEnable, bool isCheckXmlPfrEnable)
        {
            ...
        }

        ...
    }
```

so i've created my decorator like this:

```
    public class ExternalModuleControlVerifierCaller : IExternalVerifierCaller
    {
        protected IExternalVerifierCaller ExternalVerifierCaller;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IAbonentContextProvider _abonentContextProvider;

        public ExternalModuleControlVerifierCaller(IExternalVerifierCaller externalVerifierCaller, IAbonentContextProvider abonentContextProvider, ILogger logger)
        {
            ExternalVerifierCaller = externalVerifierCaller;
            _abonentContextProvider = abonentContextProvider;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public VerificationProtocol Verify(VerificationItem verificationItem)
        {
            try
            {
                SendValidateSmallFileHttp(verificationItem);

                _logger.LogInfo(
                    string.Format("Документ с id {0} отправлен на проверку в Модуль контроль",
                        verificationItem.DocumentId), LogCategoryRepository.Verification, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Ошибка проверки в Модуль Контроле: " + e.Message, LogCategoryRepository.Verification);
            }           

            return ExternalVerifierCaller.Verify(verificationItem);
        }

        public VerificationProtocolBase Verify(VerificationItems verificationItems)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var verificationItem in verificationItems)
                {
                    SendValidateSmallFileHttp(verificationItem);

                    _logger.LogInfo(
                        string.Format("Документ с id {0} отправлен на проверку в Модуль контроль", verificationItem),
                        LogCategoryRepository.Verification, null);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Ошибка проверки в Модуль Контроле: " + e.Message, LogCategoryRepository.Verification);
            }

            return ExternalVerifierCaller.Verify(verificationItems);
        }
  ....
  }
```

FormatCheck4PxVerifierCaller registered this way:

```
        .RegisterType<IExternalVerifierCaller, FormatCheck4PxVerifierCaller>(
            "FormatCheck4PxVerifierDisablePfrUfa",
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(false, true))
```

And i've tried to register it in several ways, the problem is that class FormatCheck4PxVerifierCaller has to receive some parameters in the constructor, and my solutions seems to fail to satisfy it. My solutions so far:

1)

```
    .RegisterType<IAbonentContextProvider, ThreadDependentAbonentContextProvider>()
    .RegisterType<ILogger, DefaultLoggerBridge>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
    .RegisterType<IExternalVerifierCaller, ExternalModuleControlVerifierCaller>(
        "ExternalModuleControlVerifierCaller",
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(
            container.Resolve<FormatCheck4PxVerifierCaller>(new ParameterOverride("isPfrUfaEnable", false),
                new ParameterOverride("isCheckXmlPfrEnable", true)),
            container.Resolve<IAbonentContextProvider>(), container.Resolve<ILogger>()))
```

2)

```
        .RegisterType<IAbonentContextProvider, ThreadDependentAbonentContextProvider>()
        .RegisterType<ILogger, DefaultLoggerBridge>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IExternalVerifierCaller, ExternalModuleControlVerifierCaller>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<IExternalVerifierCaller>("FormatCheck4PxVerifierDisablePfrUfa"),
                new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IAbonentContextProvider), "ThreadDependentAbonentContextProvider"),
                new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ILogger), "DefaultLoggerBridge")));
```

Do you have any suggestion how to properly register this decorator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do:

```
container
    .RegisterType<IExternalVerifierCaller, FormatCheck4PxVerifierCaller>(
        "FormatCheck4PxVerifierDisablePfrCheckXml",
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(true, false))
    .RegisterType<IExternalVerifierCaller, FormatCheck4PxVerifierCaller>(
        "FormatCheck4PxVerifierDisablePfrUfa",
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(false, true))
    .RegisterType<IExternalVerifierCaller, ExternalModuleControlVerifierCallerDecorator>(
        "ExternalModuleControlVerifierCallerDecorator", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<IExternalVerifierCaller>("FormatCheck4PxVerifierDisablePfrUfa"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IAbonentContextProvider>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<ILogger>()))
    .RegisterType<IAbonentContextProvider, ThreadDependentAbonentContextProvider>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager())
    .RegisterType<ILogger, DefaultLoggerBridge>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```